# call multiple c++ functions in python using threads

Tags: c++, python, multithreading, gil

Suppose I have a C(++) function taking an integer, and it is bound to (C)python with python api, so I can call it from python:

```
import c_module
c_module.f(10)
```

now, I want to parallelize it. The problem is: how does the GIL work in this case? Suppose I have a queue of numbers to be processed, and some workers (`threading.Thread`) working in parallel, each of them calling `c_module.f(number)` where `number` is taken from a queue.

The difference with the usual case, when GIL lock the interpreter, is that now you don't need the interpreter to evaluate `c_module.f` because it is compiled. So the question is: in this case the processing is really parallel?

Comment: I don't think will get much speed by using threads in python.  A better approach is to use OpenMP to parallelize the number crunching fortran function and call it with vectorized data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Threads currently executing the C extension code for which the GIL was explicitly released will run in parallel.  See http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock for what you need to do in your extension.

Python threads are most useful for I/O bound execution or for GUI responsiveness.  I wouldn't do python-heavy execution with threads.  If you want guaranteed parallelism, check out the `multiprocessing` library.

Comment: multiprocessing in python is not very good for my problem because every `f` function need to return a huge vector of float numbers and without shared memory it can be very expensive

Comment: Is c_module your code?  If so, are you releasing the GIL around the processing-intensive portion?

Comment: Yes, it's my code, but I don't know how to relase the GIL. If I do it, will my C++ functions run without the GIL problem?

Comment: For your purposes I would expect that all you'll need are the Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS and Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS macros since the threads are created in Python.  This will allow that thread to run in parallel with the interpreter (other thread currently with the GIL) and with any other threads that aren't waiting for the GIL (using Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS).